# Connecting PL-2303 into my Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio, usb, uart

I have a special mission to transmit 12Mbps of data from my RPi to external digital circuit.

Using the Rpi UART protocol I could achieve rather low performance.

My thought is to connect the PL-2303 (USB) to the USB of the Rpi and use the Tx PL-2303 pin as output to the circuit.

My questions are:
1. Is the above feasible?
2. where can I find the correct driver to use the PL-2303 this way? I'm using Raspbian OS

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

1. RS-232 is not GPIO-friendly: it may fry any 3.3 or 5 V input. 12 Mb/s is also the PL2303's maximum rate, so you may not be able to sustain this.
2. The driver is already included in the Raspbian kernel.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt answer mate.

1. I won't touch the Rpi GPIO's, I simply wanna connect the Tx pin to a Circuit (gate of a transistor), how this will be a problem sir?

2. Amazing, so to send data into the USB port where the PL-2303 will be located, where can I find the correct commands?